# Uncaught Reference Error in Javascript & undefined

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
var myString = new String("Hello world");
alert(myString.noSuchValue); // undefined

alert(myshit);  // This results in error, and not the above one
```

Both of them, i.e.

- property `noSuchValue` on object `myString`,
- variable `myshit`

are ***undefined***.

But why do I get an ***error*** for `myshit` and not for the ***object property case***?

[image]

Comment: The simple answer is that the language is defined to work that way. References to non-existent object properties are not errors. References to undefined variables are (usually).

Comment: @Pointy: If that is the case, then it's OK.

Comment: I agree that unexplained downvotes don't really help anyone.

Comment: @Pointy the "unless" part being among others if it's the operand to `typeof`.

Comment: @torazaburo yes that's the one I can think of; I have not had any coffee yet this morning so I lacked confidence :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the proper answer from the [ECMAScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7), but I'll summarize it in the following example:

```
var data= myObj.prop1;
```

The expected behavior is:

- if myObj (the base reference) does not exist, throw a ReferenceError.
- if the base exists, but the property not, return *undefined*

Comment: Thank you for those specs, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a slight modification of your code:

```
var myString = "Hello world";
var noSuchValue = myString.noSuchValue;
alert(noSuchValue);
```

In this example, `noSuchValue` is a **defined variable** with the value `undefined`.

Contrast this to:

```
alert(otherValue);
```

Here, `otherValue` is an **undefined variable** (i.e. a value that has not been declared with `var`), with no value whatsoever.

JavaScript can handle variables with values equal to `undefined` just fine, but it throws an exception when it sees an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you can refer to a non-existent member to assign it on an existing object, e.g.

```
var myObject = {firstMember: "test1"};
myObject.secondMember = "test2";
```

It makes sense for the value on the left hand side of the assignment to be a meaningful expression.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Because referring to a non-existent member of an object is a valid expression, but referring to a non-existent variable is not